# cuda profiler l1_global_load_hit and l1_global_load_miss return zero

Tags: cuda, profiler

I'm currently analyzing a cuda kernel (CUDA 5.0) using `nvprof`.
I try to check for uncoalesced memory loads:

```
nvprof --events l1_global_load_hit myapplication
```

returning:

```
 1         0         0         0  l1_global_load_hit
```

and:

```
nvprof --events l1_global_load_miss myapplication
```

returning

```
1         0         0         0  l1_global_load_miss
```

. Does anyone have an idea why I don't get any loads? There are definitely loads in my Kernel.

```
nvprof --events gld_request myapplication
```

returns:

```
                    1515884425251588442525158844252  gld_request
```

Thank for any help!

Comment: Is it possible that your kernel uses non-caching global memory loads? Can you show us the source?

Comment: If you use `nvvp` and run the "Kernel Memory" analysis, you'll get a simple indication of percentage utilization of global memory loads and stores which is a direct representation of coalescing.

Comment: @RoBiK I haven't turned on non-caching global memory loads for `nvcc`, is there any other way that they could be used I'm not aware of? Sorry the source is quite large, so it's not handy. I used the nvvp and it shows the message insufficient data for global load/store utilization. Which one is available depends from run to run. So I wanted to force it using `nvprof`

Comment: @RobertCrovella I tried using the `nvvp` but as mentioned in my comment above this wasn't successful. I'm not sure why, any suggestions?

Comment: non caching loads can also be initiated on an instruction by instruction basis when reading `volatile` types as well as via explicit inline assembly.  Regarding `nvvp`, I've had problems like this when I've launched either kernels with large numbers of blocks and/or programs with large numbers of kernel launches.  See if you can scale your program down for test purposes to a single kernel launch of a few hundred blocks, to see if it gets rid of the `nvvp` statistics gathering problems.

Comment: @soriak You have not specified your device. [NOTE](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-3-0): Global memory accesses for devices of compute capability 3.x are cached in L2 and for devices of compute capability 3.5, may also be cached in the read-only data cache described in the previous section; they are not cached in L1.

Answer (score 2):

For Kepler microarchitecture GPUs (Compute Capability 3.x), Default Global memory load [is not cached in L1](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#global-memory-3-0).